# Why is the error: SQLSTATE[HY000] [335544344] I/O error during "CreateFile (open)" operation for file "base2" in openserver during laravel migration?

Tags: php, laravel, firebird

I had such a problem. I can't do the migration. The error is:

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [335544344] I/O error during "CreateFile (open)"
> operation for file "base2".

I am using openserver.
Database: firebird
Framework: laravel.

I will be glad for any help!

In database wrote:

```
'firebird' => [
'driver' => 'firebird',
'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3050'),
'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'C:\Reports\base2.fdb'),
'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'SYSDBA'),
'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'masterkey'),
'charset' => env('DB_CHARSET', 'UTF8'),
'engine_version' => '3.0.0',
]
```

Comment: you should avoid to write username and password here on stackoverflow

Comment: what is this `env('DB_DATABASE', 'C:\Reports\base2.fdb')` ??

Comment: @Abdulla Nilam This is the path to the database file

Comment: @GiacomoM SYSDBA is the standard admin user of Firebird, and masterkey is the widely known default admin password (which you shouldn't use in production systems).

Comment: The error suggests that you might have an entry `C:\Reports\base2.fdb = base2` in your aliases.conf (Firebird 2.5 and earlier) or databases.conf (Firebird 3.0 and later), instead of the other way around. This means that Firebird will redirect a request for database file `C:\Reports\base2.fdb` to a database file `base2`, which does not exist. Alternatively, the server might be trying to create a lock file or temporary file and fails because of lack of access rights (though that would usually be reflected in secondary error information, IIRC).

Comment: It might make more sense to ask about this on [firebird-support](https://groups.google.com/g/firebird-support), because I think this might require some troubleshooting, and Stack Overflow is not really a good venue for that.

Comment: One thing to consider, I'm not sure about PHP strings, but is it possible that `'C:\Reports\base2.fdb'` should be `'C:\\Reports\\base2.fdb'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone obviously defined laravel environment variable DB_DATABASE to value 'base2'. Search and destroy!

Otherwise a simpler and better solution is **not to use** function env() in your code. Using external configuration is convenient sometimes but it opens a door for every king of misconfiguration that are hard to investigate. In the case of PHP it is also a door for hackers.